# XMLPullparser getEventType returns 0 everyTime

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I've been trying to parse XML file but the getEventType method always returns 0. and the While loop is executing forever.

```
public class FlowerPullParser 

{

public static List<Flower> parseFed(String content) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

    parser.setInput(new StringReader(content));

    int eventType = parser.getEventType();

    do
    {

        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            Log.i("start-tag",parser.getText());


        else if(eventType ==  XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
            Log.i("End-tag",parser.getText());

        else if(eventType ==  XmlPullParser.TEXT)
            Log.i("Text-tag",parser.getText());


    eventType = parser.next();  
    }while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);
    return null;

}
    }
```

Here is the link from where I fetch the XML

[Flowers.xml](http://services.hanselandpetal.com/feeds/flowers.xml)

XML is properly coming (through variable content) ,seems my code has some mistakes but I couldn't understand what have I done wrong.
Answers and Advises need

thanks!

Comment: can you please post your xml string ?

Comment: @Haresh Question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(content.replace("&","&amp;")));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("Start document");
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
```

Comment: voila! Thanks man but can you please tell me what are these line mean {factory.setNamespaceaware(true) } and why did you change the content???

Comment: Which is specifies that the parsers created by this factory will provide support for XML namespaces. By default the value of this is set to false and in your xml "&" break parsing so i have try to replace it "&amp;".